# React native application start crash [ios]

Tags: ios, react-native

Some ios version has app crash.

The app started and turned off after a few seconds.

Our tried ios version up then some ios phone solve this issues.

My Conjecture is firebase issue
this is my error report please help me

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: TCC 0 
This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSUserTrackingUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Triggered by Thread:  3

Application Specific Information:
CoreSimulator 783.5 - Device: iPhone 11 Pro (60FEA29F-5103-487C-B421-B5C031AB0D88) - Runtime: iOS 14.4 (18D46) - DeviceType: iPhone 11 Pro
dyld4 config: DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot

Kernel Triage:
VM - pmap_enter failed with resource shortage

Error Formulating Crash Report:
thread_get_state(PAGEIN) returned 0x10000003: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
thread_get_state(EXCEPTION) returned 0x10000003: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
thread_get_state(FLAVOR) returned 0x10000003: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
```

Comment: Error describes the issue. You need to add [NSUserTrackingUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsusertrackingusagedescription) to info.plist through xcode.

Answer (score 1):

A significant change in iOS is that you must declare ahead of time any access to private data or your App will crash.

Once you link with iOS you must declare access to any user private data types. You do this by adding a usage key to your app’s Info.plist together with a purpose string. The list of frameworks that count as private data is a long one

**Contacts, Calendar, Reminders, Photos, Bluetooth Sharing, Microphone, Camera, Location, Health, HomeKit, Media Library, Motion, CallKit, Speech Recognition, SiriKit, TV Provider.**

You need to put the **NSCameraUsageDescription** in your plist.

```
<key> NSCameraUsageDescription </key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) uses Cameras</string>
```